# Function with optional paramaters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function with optional parameters.

```
function RetvinkletTrekant(par1, par2, par3, par4, par5, par6){

    if (par1) {var a = par1}
    if (par2) {var b = par2}
    if (par3) {var c = par3}
    if (par4) {var A = par4}
    if (par5) {var B = par5}
    if (par6) {var C = par6}

    document.write(A);
}

RetvinkletTrekant(null, null, null, 4, null, null);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're looking for *optional* parameters, not *optimal* ones.

Comment: What's your question? Doesn't your code work as intended, what else did you expect?

Comment: pass in a args hash like args[par1] ... is just easier

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually asking about **"optional parameters"** rather than **"optimal parameters"** then the best way to do it would be to use a object like so.

```
function RetvinkletTrekant(a){

    if (a.par1) { var a = a.par1; }
    if (a.par2) { var b = a.par2; }
    if (a.par3) { var c = a.par3; }
    if (a.par4) { var A = a.par4; }
    if (a.par5) { var B = a.par5; }
    if (a.par6) { var C = a.par6; }

    document.write(A);
}

RetvinkletTrekant({
    par1: 4
});
```

Comment: You can (should) also omit those `if`-statements. If the properties don't exist, the variables would be `undefined` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refactor function to use one parameter. Change

```
function RetvinkletTrekant(par1, par2, par3, par4, par5, par6) {
// ...
}
```

to something like this

```
function RetvinkletTrekant(config) {
// ...
}
```

where config is an object containing your *optional* parameters:

```
RetvinkletTrekant({par1: "foo", par5: "bar"});
```